# jquery datatables conflict with bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I can't resolve Datatables issue with bootstrap tabbed href. I When table is loading from datatable, then bootstrap tab doesn't work. I can't debug where is error in datatable plugin or in bootstrap

**datatable**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "columnDefs": [ {
              "targets": 0,
              "orderable": false,
              "searchable": false 
        } ],
        "ajax":{
              // .....
                }
            });
        });
```

If I remove this line - then bootstrap tab works. At other side datatable doesn't work.

```
"serverSide": true,
```

**bootstrap tab**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Manage Section</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#2" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>Add Section</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check your browser's console if you see some errors there

Comment: @SaurabhSharma. There is only Source map error in console

Comment: Oh, problem in CSS, fixed it.